# Equivalence of Groovy @Delegate in C#

Tags: c#, groovy

Groovy has the following [@Delegate feature](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.ng/2009/08/groovy-goodness-delegate-to-simplify.html) that can be used to import the methods of a class into another class and use them as if they were part of the class:

```
class Worker {
   def work() { // do something }
}

class Manager {
   @Delegate Worker subordinate = new Worker();
}

def manager = new Manager();
manager.work() //
```

The `work` method does not exist in Manager class but I could still call it. Here it using the work method on the `subordinate` instance.

Is there a similar approach in C# and if not, how can one achieve this with C#?

The best I could come up with is

```
public class Manager
{
   protected readonly Worker subordinate = new Worker();

   public Worker Subordinate { 
     get { return this.subordinate; }
   }
}

var manager = new Manager();
manager.Subordinate.work();
```

Comment: C# doesn't have a direct equivalent for this.  You could achieve almost the same thing through inheritance or composition.